# How to refresh vue.js application automatically as soon as sql table data has changed?

Tags: sql, azure, vue.js, entity-framework

I want to show different kind of notes in my vue.js application to inform the user for example about an upcoming maintenance. I thought at an info "banner" under the application header. The data like period of the maintenance I would store in a sql database. In this database I want to regular when the banner should be visible or even not. Maybe with a table column called active.
Now I am looking for a solution how to trigger the vue.js application to refresh if data in database was added/updated.

Can someone help me please?

Are there any other ideas (maybe more professional ideas) how to trigger a note "banner" in a vue.js application?
The application will be hosted in Azure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either you call a backend periodically to know are there changes or not. Or you should for using something lie Socket.io to communicate between a client and a server in realtime

Answer (score 0):

Anatoly answer is right, those are your two options. You either make a request to your backend service every couple of minutes(depends how fast this info is changing) or you implement a web socket that will let your frontend now when the info has changed. It depends on how big is the app and what use you're going to give it, personally, in a scenario like this i would go with a web socket.

Here you have a nice library i've used in the past: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-socket.io . You will also need to make some implementation in your backend service to handle the info gathering.